# How do i limit the list of data being rendered for a particular list in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create an app that when the user clicks on create button a survey question with four answers gets created. The goal is that in a single list the user can maximum add up to 4 questions and a minimum of 1 question. So when the user tries to add another question after the 4th question a new survey list should be created. So one survey list can contain a maximum of four questions.

```
//Survey.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import "./Survey.css";
import CreateSurvey from "../modals/CreateSurvey";
import Card from "../card/Card";

const Survey = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [surveyList, setSurveyList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let arr = localStorage.getItem("surveyList");
    if (arr) {
      let obj = JSON.parse(arr);
      setSurveyList(obj);
    }
  }, []);

  // const surveyListArray = [];
  // while (surveyList.length > 0) {
  //   surveyListArray.push(surveyList.splice(0, 3));
  // }

  const deleteSurvey = (index) => {
    let tempList = surveyList;
    tempList.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("surveyList", JSON.stringify(tempList));
    setSurveyList(tempList);
    window.location.reload();
  };

  const toggle = () => {
    setModal(!modal);
  };

  const updateListArray = (obj, index) => {
    let tempList = surveyList;
    tempList[index] = obj;
    localStorage.setItem("surveyList", JSON.stringify(tempList));
    setSurveyList(tempList);
    window.location.reload();
  };

  const saveSurvey = (surveyObj) => {
    let tempList = surveyList;
    tempList.push(surveyObj);
    localStorage.setItem("surveyList", JSON.stringify(tempList));
    setSurveyList(surveyList);
    setModal(false);
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="header text-center">
        <h5>Survey</h5>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => setModal(true)}>
          Create Survey
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="survey-container">
        {surveyList &&
          surveyList.map((obj, index) => (
            <Card
              surveyObj={obj}
              index={index}
              deleteSurvey={deleteSurvey}
              updateListArray={updateListArray}
            >
              <input type="radio" name="answerOne" />
            </Card>
          ))}
      </div>
      <CreateSurvey toggle={toggle} modal={modal} save={saveSurvey} />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Survey;
```

//Card.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Card.css";
import EditSurvey from "../modals/EditSurvey";

const Card = ({ surveyObj, deleteSurvey, index, updateListArray }) => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setModal(!modal);
  };

  const updateSurvey = (obj) => {
    updateListArray(obj, index);
  };

  const deleteHandler = () => {
    deleteSurvey(index);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card-wrapper mr-5">
        <div className="card-top"></div>
        <div className="survey-holder">
          <span className="card-headers">{surveyObj.name}</span>
          <span className="check">
            <input type="radio" className="radio" />
            <p className="answer"> {surveyObj.answerOne}</p>
          </span>
          <span className="check">
            <input type="radio" className="radio" />
            <p className="answer"> {surveyObj.answerTwo}</p>
          </span>
          <span className="check">
            <input type="radio" className="radio" />
            <p className="answer"> {surveyObj.answerThree}</p>
          </span>
          <span className="check">
            <input type="radio" className="radio" />
            <p className="answer"> {surveyObj.answerFour}</p>
          </span>
          <div className="icons">
            <i className="far fa-edit edit" onClick={() => setModal(true)}></i>
            <i className="fas fa-trash-alt delete" onClick={deleteHandler}></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <EditSurvey
          modal={modal}
          toggle={toggle}
          updateSurvey={updateSurvey}
          surveyObj={surveyObj}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

//CreateSurvey.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";
import { Fragment } from "react";

const CreateSurvey = ({ modal, toggle, save }) => {
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");
  const [answerOne, setAnswerOne] = useState("");
  const [answerTwo, setAnswerTwo] = useState("");
  const [answerThree, setAnswerThree] = useState("");
  const [answerFour, setAnswerFour] = useState("");

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    if (name === "question") {
      setQuestion(value);
    } else if (name === "answerOne") {
      setAnswerOne(value);
    } else if (name === "answerTwo") {
      setAnswerTwo(value);
    } else if (name === "answerThree") {
      setAnswerThree(value);
    } else {
      setAnswerFour(value);
    }
  };

  const saveHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let surveyObj = {};
    surveyObj["name"] = question;
    surveyObj["answerOne"] = answerOne;
    surveyObj["answerTwo"] = answerTwo;
    surveyObj["answerThree"] = answerThree;
    surveyObj["answerFour"] = answerFour;
    save(surveyObj);
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Create a Survey Question</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <form>
            <div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Survey Questions</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={question}
                  name="question"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <label>Survey Answers</label>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Answer 1</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control mt-2 mb-2"
                  value={answerOne}
                  name="answerOne"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Answer 2</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control mt-2 mb-2"
                  value={answerTwo}
                  name="answerTwo"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Answer 3</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control mt-2 mb-2"
                  value={answerThree}
                  name="answerThree"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Answer 4</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control mt-2 mb-2"
                  value={answerFour}
                  name="answerFour"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={saveHandler}>
            Create
          </Button>
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggle}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default CreateSurvey;
```

Comment: It depends a lot what you want in your user experience. When you say that `a new survey list should be created` you mean that the user will be unabled to create more and force him to save before continue or he enters N questions and your website do the trick to split into multiples surveys. It depends

Comment: Is it possible for an application to do the trick to split into multiple surveys of a maximum of four questions?  I was actually thinking of forcing the user to save.  But now i would prefer the other one. Could you please suggest me how. Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't work as you describe in your question. Because the user is not enabled to add more than one question, am I right? If it is true, there is no problem, I just want to understand what we are looking at to know how to help

Comment: Currently the user is able to add to n number of question so I want to limit to max 4 questions for each list and minimum 1